# Java - How do I see if a character matches multiple characters?

Tags: java, arrays, char, stringbuilder

**Java Code**

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("");

    char[] vowels = { 'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u' };

    while (true) {
        if(!(sb.charAt(0).matches(vowels))) <---- Need help {
            sb.append(scan.nextLine());
            break;
        }
        else {
            sb.delete(0, sb.length()-1);
            sb.append(scan.nextLine());
        }
    }
```

I'm trying to make it so that if the first letter of the user inputted word is a vowel, he/she has to re-enter a word. StringBuilder doesn't provide the `matches` method so I need an alternative to check this for me. Also, I can't use a string since I'm also using a `charAt` method later in this code.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use BitSet

```
static BitSet vowels = new BitSet();

static {
    vowels.set('a');
    vowels.set('e');
    vowels.set('i');
    vowels.set('o');
    vowels.set('u');
}
```

Then when you want to check, in a method do

```
if (vowels.get(someChar)) {
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the built-in [`indexOf()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf-int-) method of `String`:

```
String vowels = "aeiou";

if (vowels.indexOf(sb.charAt(0)) == -1/*not found*/) {
```

As the javadoc says it:

> Returns the index of the first occurrence of the character in the character sequence represented by this object, or **-1 if the character does not occur**.

Answer (score 0):

Best way ti use regex like:

```
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("[aeiou]").matcher(str);
```

Comment: Is there a simpler way because honestly this is beyond my knowledge xd

Comment: You can use switch case.

Answer (score 0):

another option is to use  a collection Set

```
Set<Character> myVowelList = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'));
String aRandomName = "sdadasdas";
if (myVowelList.contains(Character.toLowerCase(aRandomName.charAt(0)))) {
    System.out.println("Yes it is there!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int flag=0;
    char[] a = {'a','e','i','o','u'};
    System.out.println("Enter a word");
     String word=sc.next();
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        if(word.charAt(0) == a[i]){
            System.out.println("Starts with a vowel");
            flag=1;
        }
    }
    if(flag != 1)
    {
        System.out.println("Word Doesnt start with vowel");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yet another way...

```
private static final char[] VOWELS = { 'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u' };

public boolean startsWithVowel(String s) {
    char first=s.charAt(0);
    for (char c : VOWELS) if (c==first) return true;
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use RegEx

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("");

String vowelsRegEx = "[aeiou].*";
/* [aeiou] = First character: a or e or i or o or u
 * .* = All characters after the first: doesn't matter
 */

if(!sb.toString().matches(vowelsRegEx)) {
    sb.append(scan.nextLine());
    break;
}
else {
    sb.delete(0, sb.length()-1);
    sb.append(scan.nextLine());
}
```

If you are new to regular expressions, you can easily test your RegEx-String on [RegEx101](https://regex101.com/)